# How to stop audio played by audio tag of HTML5

Tags: javascript, audio, html

I am new to HTML5 and I am exploring HTML5 features. There I came across audio tag.
I written code with it to play sound files. 
I am having one problem with this tag. On button click, I want to change the sound file stopping the previous one.
I searched a lot but didn't find anything.
Please help me to stop the sound played by audio tag.

Here is my code;

```
  try
  {
       if(MyAudio != undefined)
       {
          MyAudio = null;
       }
       MyAudio = new Audio("filename");
       MyAudio.play();
  }
  catch(v)
  {
    //alert(v.message);
  }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
  try
  {
       if(MyAudio != undefined)
       {
          MyAudio.pause();
       }
       MyAudio = new Audio("filename");
       MyAudio.play();
  }
  catch(v)
  {
    //alert(v.message);
  }
```

Comment: Just tried, it works fine (on Chrome), without using pause. Just changing the SRC stops ad restarts the sound without lags.

Comment: You know thats kinda ugly method

Answer (score 3):

As commented in this cuestión: [HTML5 Audio stop function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834520/html5-audio-stop-function), a better solution could be:

```js
var sound = document.getElementById("audio");
sound.pause();
sound.currentTime = 0;
```