# Stopping a html5 player when div is hidden

Tags: jquery, html

Is is possible to stop an HTML5 audio player with an onClick that also hides a div? I'm having difficulty trying to figure it out.

```
   $(function() { 
    $('#box').hide();
    $('#loading').hide();
    $( "#box" ).draggable({handle:'h3'}); 

});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#body').load('body.php', function(){
$('.stars, .ship').click(function(){
                    var name = $(this).attr('name');
                    var type = $(this).attr('type');
                    var linkvar = 'content.php?eid=';
                    var link_full = linkvar + name;
                    $('#box').show('slow');
                    $('#box_content').addClass(type);

                    $('#box_content').load(link_full, 
                        function() 
                        {
                        $(function(){ $('#close_this_box').click(
                            function(){
                                    $('.player').pause();
                                    $('#box').hide('slow'); 
                            });
                                });
                        $('.event').click(function() 
                        {
                            var name = $(this).attr('name');
                            var linkvar = 'content.php?cid=';
                            var link_full = linkvar + name;
                            $('#loading').show();
                            $('#box_content').load(link_full, 
                            function()
                                { 

                                });
                        });
                        });
                });});

});
                $('.ship, .stars').hover(
                function()
                { 
                    $(this).children('div').removeClass('hidden');
                      if ($(this).children('div').offset().left + 200 > $(window).width()) {       
                     $(this).children('ul').css('right', 180);  } 
                }, 
                function(){ $(this).children('div:nth-child(2)').addClass('hidden');});
```

(These are words because I have nothing else to add and this thing won't let me post it. I apologize for this stupidity here.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834520/html5-audio-stop-function

Comment: I've looked at that and cannot get it to work.

Comment: Can you at least paste in an example of the code you're using?