# Stop html sound with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am not really experienced with the use of javascript so this question could be a bit silly. I'm currently trying to develope a soundboard. Everything is working fine except one thing, i want to stop a sound when another button is clicked and i really don't know how i can do this.

**That's an example for what i want to do:**
I click button 1, the sound is played and while the sound is still playing I click button 2 and the sound of button 1 stops while the sound of button 2 starts to play.(And so on with every button)

**Html code:**

```js
function EvalSound(soundobj) {
  var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
  thissound.play();
}
```

```css
audio {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
  <audio class="audio" id="a" src="" controls preload="auto" autobuffer></audio>
  <audio class="audio" id="b" src="b.wav" controls preload="auto" autobuffer></audio>
  <audio class="audio" id="c" src="c.mp3" controls preload="auto" autobuffer></audio>



  <input type="button" class="button" value="Button 1" onClick="EvalSound('a')">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Button 2" onClick="EvalSound('b')">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Button 3" onClick="EvalSound('c')">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `thissound.pause()`, it will stop the sound from playing. What you want to do is to be able to call `thissound.pause()` after your function has reached its end, and local variables have been erased. This means that you'll need to store it in a global variable, which you could call `currentsound`, for example, so you can access it in another call of `EvalSound`. What this would get you is something like this:

```
var currentsound;
function EvalSound(soundobj) {
    currentsound.pause();
    var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
    thissound.play();
    currentsound = thissound;
}
```

This gives us 2 problems, however. When you call `EvalSound`, the previous sound gets paused, and when it's called again for the same sound, it will start from where it was when you paused it. Therefore we need to set the time at which it needs to start playing. The other problem is that when you first call `EvalSound`, `currentsound` will be undefined, and calling `currentsound.pause();` will result in an error. To solve this, we can add the following to it:

```
var currentsound;
function EvalSound(soundobj) {
    if(currentsound)
    {
        currentsound.pause();
    }
    var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
    thissound.currentTime = 0;
    thissound.play();
    currentsound = thissound;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `pause` method for audio elements. You can use it the same way you use `play`.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_pause.asp

Answer (score 0):

Something similar was mentioned in this question: [HTML5 Audio stop function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834520/html5-audio-stop-function).

`Javascript` has a useful method when dealing with audio and that method is `pause()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if clicking second button (id=b), stop first button invoking sound (id=a)

```
var sound_a = document.getElementById('a');
a.pause();
a.currentTime = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you, you just need something like this in js:

```js
function EvalSound(soundobj) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('audio').map(function(thissound) {
    if(thissound.id == soundobj) {
      thissound.start();
    }
    else {
      thissound.pause();
    }
  });
}
```