# How do I play same sound again by pausing the previous instance?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have a sound instance that plays when the player collides with an object.

```
  var coin = new Audio('sounds/coin.wav');
  if(type == 2){  //Coin Box
    coin.play();
  }
```

The problem is , when the player collides with multiple objects of the same kind, the sound doesnt play again as it is already playing.
How do i stop the previous sound and play it again? also without having to create another instance of the same sound.

Something like this.

```
    if(type == 2){ 
      coin.pause();
      coin.play();
    }
```

Comment: Go through this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/14836099/2968762

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the time back to the start.

```
coin.pause();
coin.currentTime = 0;
coin.play();
```