# Pausing audio on Div hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I managed to get the audio to play on hover but I can't get it to pause when my mouse leaves the area.

FIddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/nLm9bxnw/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var audio = $("#audio-1")[0];
$(".box").hover
(function() {
    audio.play();
  },
(function(){
 audio.stop();
});
});
```

```css
.box{
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  font-size:25px;
  color:white;
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio controls id="audio-1">
  <source src="http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%20Major.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<div class="box">
If you Hover me, the song will play!
</div>
```

Comment: The fiddle doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `audio.pause()` not `.stop()`. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var audio = $("#audio-1")[0];
  $('.box').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      audio.play();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      audio.pause();
    }
  });
});
```

This will resume where it stopped. If you want to start from the beginning, as one of the other answers suggested, you would need to include `audio.currentTime = 0;` before the `start` or after the `pause` invocation.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nLm9bxnw/7/

Answer (score 1):

`stop` really isn't a javascript method for audio and video file manipulation. Rather use one of the following:

```
audio.pause();
audio.currentTime = 0;
```

See [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834520/html5-audio-stop-function)

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var audio = $("#audio-1")[0];
$(".box").hover
(function() {audio.play();});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/Ln8q8739/

Comment: Your javascript has a error in close function. With this example, when the mouse hover div, the song play!