# How to play/pause sound and the sound play from the begininng of the sound?

Tags: javascript, audio

i want the user to be able to click on  al link and the sound will start to play if the user click again on the link it stops and the if again it play but from the sound will strat from the beginning and nod from whrere it stop before.
my code now is just a simple toggle if the sound:

```js
var partOne = document.getElementById("part1");
function PlayPart1() {
  return partOne.paused ? partOne.play() : partOne.pause();
};
```

```html
  <p>
<a   class="textAudio" onClick="PlayPart1()">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
</a>
    </p>
 <audio id="part1" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Audio stop function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834520/html5-audio-stop-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use currentTime. Make current time 0 like this -

```js
var partOne = document.getElementById("part1");
function PlayPart1() {
partOne.currentTime = 0
  return partOne.paused ? partOne.play() : partOne.pause();
};
```

```html
  <p>
<a   class="textAudio" onClick="PlayPart1()">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
</a>
    </p>
 <audio id="part1" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Comment: @Sivan_G - Happy coding :) and please accept answer if working properly. :P