# Disable second audio player when the other is playing in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have two audio files on the page and I would want the user to listen to just one audio at once while disabling the other. I think some kind of javascript needs to be inserted.

```
 <audio controls="" controlsList="nodownload">
                      <source src="audio/audio1.mp3" 
                      type="audio/mpeg">
                      Your browser does not support the
                      audio element. </audio>
 <audio controls="" controlsList="nodownload">
                      <source src="audio/audio2.mp3" 
                      type="audio/mpeg">
                      Your browser does not support the
                      audio element. </audio>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "What have you tried?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript to stop playing sound when another starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43430897/javascript-to-stop-playing-sound-when-another-starts)