# cancel an if statement if another statement comes true

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, html5-audio

I have this function that plays different sounds to different keys. But if I press a key, then press another key right away, the previous sound will still play.

My question is, how do I cancel the previous sound when a new one is played?

Here's the code:

```js
    
 window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);

    function checkKeyPressed(evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode == "81") { //q
            document.getElementById('enklyd').play();
        }
        if (evt.keyCode == "87") { //w
            document.getElementById('lyd1').play();
        }
        if (evt.keyCode == "69") { //e
            document.getElementById('lyd2').play();
        }
        if (evt.keyCode == "82") { //r
            document.getElementById('lyd3').play();
        }
        if (evt.keyCode == "84") { //t
            document.getElementById('lyd4').play();
        }
        if (evt.keyCode == "89") { //y
            document.getElementById('lyd5').play();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for any solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834520/html5-audio-stop-function

Comment: I've read that post. I am pretty new to js, and certainly have not looked in to jquery and therefore didn't get any help from that post

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a matter of "stopping" the if statement because they are individually doing their job correctly. What you want to stop is the sound clip being played.

For this you can use the `.pause()` method, set the `.currentTime` to `0`, or I believe you can also set the volume to 0 and just let it play out.

As mentioned in a comment, there are a few SO questions that may have already answered this. Is there a unique situation that isn't being answered in those?

Answer (score 0):

I think this works for you:

```
var e = document.getElementById('enklyd');
function checkKeyPressed(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == "81") { //q
        e.pause();
        e.currentTime = 0;
        e = document.getElementById('enklyd');
        e.play();
    }
    if (evt.keyCode == "87") { //w
        e.pause();
        e.currentTime = 0;
        e = document.getElementById('lyd1');
        e.play();
    }
    if (evt.keyCode == "69") { //e
        e.pause();
        e.currentTime = 0;
        e = document.getElementById('lyd2');
        e.play();
    }
    if (evt.keyCode == "82") { //r
        e.pause();
        e.currentTime = 0;
        e = document.getElementById('lyd3');
        e.play();
    }
    if (evt.keyCode == "84") { //t
        e.pause();
        e.currentTime = 0;
        e = document.getElementById('lyd4');
        e.play();
    }
    if (evt.keyCode == "89") { //y
        e.pause();
        e.currentTime = 0;
        e = document.getElementById('lyd5');
        e.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this error message showed: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of undefined
    at checkKeyPressed

Comment: @ff29 I have just updated my answer. Look at the top of the code block.

Comment: If it fails even with that first line, it must be because of the context of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the issue is not regarding the `if` condition. But you can try the following code, I think this will work fine for you.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);

var keyMap = {
    "81": "enklyd", //q
    "87": "lyd1", //w
    "69": "lyd2", //e
    "82": "lyd3", //r
    "84": "lyd4", //t
    "89": "lyd5", //y
};

var prevPlayed = null, target = null, prevTarget = null;

function checkKeyPressed(evt) {

    prevTarget = document.getElementById(keyMap[prevPlayed])
    target = document.getElementById(keyMap[evt.keyCode]);

    if (prevPlayed !== null && prevTarget !== null)
        prevTarget.pause();

    if (keyMap[evt.keyCode] && target !== null) {
        target.currentTime = 0;
        target.play();
    }

    prevPlayed = evt.keyCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'switch' instead of using 'if'.Just add a common class to all your elements

```
const yourDiv = document.querySelector('yourDiv');
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);

function checkKeyPressed(evt) {
    yourDiv.currentTime = 0;
    switch(evt) {
        case '81':                
            document.getElementById('enklyd').play();
            break;
        case '87' :
            document.getElementById('lyd1').play();
            break;
        case '69' :
            document.getElementById('lyd2').play();
            break;
        case '82' :
            document.getElementById('lyd3').play();
            break;
        case '84' :
            document.getElementById('lyd4').play();
            break;
        case '89' :
            document.getElementById('lyd5').play();
            break;
        default :
            return null;
        }
}
```