# How to play audio on touchstart until touchend event

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I want to play an audio of 1sec play on `touchstart` and ends at `touchend` event. I want it for piano button in my web project without using any library or framework.

Comment: Create an audio element and call its methods in the event handlers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834520/html5-audio-stop-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 Audio stop function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834520/html5-audio-stop-function)