How to have the control over the audio playing when text is converted to speech using Azure Speech Service?
Below is the code I am using to convert text to audio for a button click using Azure speech service, but I am unable to stop the audio that is playing,
I would like to use the same button to stop the audio while it is playing.
How to have the control over the audio that is playing.
Is there a way to have control on audio with or without saving it to a .wav file?
const speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription("key",
"region");
let synthesizer = null;

function initializeSynthesizer() {
    const audioConfig = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromDefaultSpeakerOutput();
    synthesizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
    synthesizer.synthesizing = (s, e) => {
        console.log(`Synthesizing: ${e.result.audioData.byteLength
        } bytes`);
    };
}

function convertTextToSpeech(text) {
    if (!synthesizer) {
        initializeSynthesizer();
    }

    let selectedLanguage = TranslationModule.getSelectedLanguage(); // Assuming TranslationModule handles language selection
    TranslationModule.translateText(text, selectedLanguage).then(translatedText => {
        synthesizer.speakTextAsync(
            translatedText,
            result => {
                if (result.reason === SpeechSDK.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted) {
                    console.log("Speech synthesis completed.");
            } else {
                    console.error("Speech synthesis canceled, " + result.errorDetails);
            }
        },
            error => {
                console.error("Error during speech synthesis:", error);
        }
        );

        console.log("Speech synthesis started:", text); // Log synthesis started
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error translating text for speech:', error);
    });
}

$(document).off('click').on('click', '#btnread', function () {
    let textToRead = this.getAttribute('data-text'); // Assuming the button has a 'data-text' attribute with the text to read
    convertTextToSpeech(textToRead);
});


(1)

unable to stop the audio that is playing, I would like to use the same
button to stop the audio while it is playing. How to have the control over the audio that is playing.

See
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53204874/3728901
quote
sound.pause();
sound.currentTime = 0;

(2)

Is there a way to have control on audio with saving it to a .wav file?

Yes. See above.
(3)

Is there a way to have control without saving it to a
.wav file?

A vague question. "A white fox is a white fox." , you can control playing by split to "A white fox" or "A white fox is a", etc.
For workaround, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech?tabs=streaming
