# how to get notification sounds only reads one time only if there is new data entry

Tags: jquery

I have a code, and code work, but the sounds always running / play, I hope the sounds just once playing if there is a new data entry, but can not. I hope my friends can help me. thnk

```
       function notification(){

        $('<audio id="chatAudio"><source src="../sound/notify.ogg" type="audio/ogg"><source 
           src="../sound/notify.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><source src="../sound/notify.wav" 
           type="audio/wav"></audio>').appendTo('body');

        $.ajax({
            url:"check.php",
            chace: false,
            success: function(data){
                if(data == 0){
                    $(".place").hide();
                }else{
                    $(".place").show("fast");
                    $(".place").html(data);
                    $('#chatAudio')[0].play();
                }
            }
        }).always(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){notification()}, 3000);       
        }); 
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
   notification();
});
```

Comment: you can use `.play()`, `.pause()` methods in javascript on sound object ie on `#chatAudio`. For more see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566967/how-to-stop-audio-played-by-audio-tag-of-html5

Comment: @Vedant how to define

Comment: Move the adding of the `audio` element out of the notification function as you'll end up appending it many times currently.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it will work if you move the adding of the audio element to outside of the `notification` function so it only gets added once.  I have refactored your code somewhat and it ought to work as intended.  Just make sure that your PHP is returning 0 when there are no new notifications.  Also I am unsure what `chace` means in your JS?

```
       function notification(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"check.php",
            chace: false,  //<-- Not sure what this is meant to be?!
            success: function(data){
                if(data == 0){
                    $(".place").hide();
                }else{
                    $(".place").show("fast");
                    $(".place").html(data);
                    $('#chatAudio')[0].play();
                }
            }
        }); 
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('<audio id="chatAudio"><source src="../sound/notify.ogg" type="audio/ogg"><source 
           src="../sound/notify.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><source src="../sound/notify.wav" 
           type="audio/wav"></audio>').appendTo('body');

   var notificationInterval = setInterval(function(){notification();}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: mmmm, this good, thnk for your solution.. By the way in the manufacture of JS if any will result in memory ram ride continue?

Comment: If I understand correctly you're wondering whether this should increase RAM usage continuously?  I don't think so.  Have a look though in the Profile tab of Google Chromes developer tools if you are concerned.